# Inner Join a SubQuery with Fluent NHibernate Criteria and DetachedCriteria

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, criteria

I need to write the following SQL as a Fluent NHIbernate Criteria in order to support order and paging. I feel like I'm really close.

```
SELECT  stats.* 
FROM
    ItemStatistic stats
    INNERJOIN
        (   SELECT admin.AdministrationCode, is.ItemStatisticId,
                RANK() OVER(Partition BY admin.AdministrationCode ORDERBY is.StatDate DESC) AS RowNm
            FROM
                ItemStatistic is
                INNERJOIN ItemInstance ii ON ii.ItemInstanceId = is.ItemInstanceId
                INNERJOIN Administration admin ON ii.AdministrationId = admin.AdministrationId
            WHERE
                ii.itemId = @ItemId
        ) sub ON stats.ItemStatisticId = sub.ItemStatisticId AND sub.RowNm = 1
```

I've created the subquery as a detached criteria as follows

```
var subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(ItemStatistic), "stats")
                .CreateAlias("stats.ItemInstance", "ii")
                .CreateAlias("ii.Administration", "admin")
                .SetProjection
                (
                    Projections.SqlProjection(

                        "stats.ItemStatisticId, RANK() OVER(Partition BY admin.AdministrationCode ORDER BY stats.StatDate DESC) AS RowNm",
                        new string[] { "ItemStatisticId", "RowNm" },
                        new IType[] { NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Int32, NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.Int32 }
                    )
                )
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ii.ItemId", itemId));
```

But I can't figure out how to inner join the subquery.  I would think it would be similar to the following, which does not work.  Possibly I just need to understand how to alias the subquery?

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<ItemStatistic>("is")
                .Add(Subqueries.Eq("ItemStatisticId", subQuery)  // need alias for subquery aka sq ?
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("sq.RowNm", 1)));
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("is.ItemStatisticId", "sq.ItemStatisticId"))
```